# PHP while loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables, while-loop

I have this very simple Wordpress while loop:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( args ) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
   $data = grab_something( args );
   echo $data;
   echo "<br/";   
endwhile;
```

This gives me something like:

```
datastring1
datastring2
anotherdata
somethingelse
and else
and so forth
(...)
```

I want to save these values from while loop as an array or variables, eg.

```
$data1 = "datastring1";
$data2 = "datastring2";
$data3 = "anotherdata";
(...)
```

How to? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter `$i` to keep track of the number, and then you can save the results either as an array or as a set of variables.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( args ) );

$i = 0;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
   $data = grab_something( args );
   $i++;
   $array[] = $data; // Saves into an array.
   ${"data".$i} = $data; // Saves into variables.
endwhile;
```

You only need to use the `$i` counter if you use the second method. If you save into an array with the above syntax, the indexes will be generated automatically.

Comment: While this does work and answers the OP's exact question, I'm having trouble imagining a use case where this pattern is preferable to the alternative solution proposed by @Shakti Singh.

Comment: @Schwartzie, agreed, which is why I included the bit about using an `array`. They're really just different semantics for the very same functionality, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can save in array easily

```
    $array=array();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        $data = grab_something( args );
        $array[]=$data;

    endwhile;
```

`print_r($data);`

`$array` will store data from index 0 to the number of elements while loop iterate

Comment: Maybe also mention the ability to assign dynamic variable names, which is essentially what is the OP after, not an array (not that it's more efficent), with `${$name}`...

Comment: this doesn't work, when I do var_dump($array) outside the while loop it gives me only ONE last $data string...

Comment: @Wordpressor: You might be doing something wrong anywhere please check you code again.